# SharePoint online error message when applying a modern site template

Tags: templates, sharepoint, upload

I saved a SharePoint online modern site as a template and tried to install it to a different site collection within the same tenant. Uploading and activating the .wsp solution worked but when I went to select it as a custom template I received the following error message:

[Features not activated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAUux.png)

I then used PowerShell to activate the hidden features as described here:

https://praveensharepointknowledgebase.wordpress.com/2018/02/28/activate-hidden-site-features-using-powershell/

I'm now getting the following error message:

Sorry, something went wrong 
The field specified with name _TopicHeader and ID {d60d65ff-ff42-4044-a684-ac3f7a5e598c} is not accessible or does not exist.

[TopicHeader does not exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgBPm.png)

I have been searching the forums for similar messages but so far no luck.

Thoughts?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be posted in https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com

Comment: Sure, no problem. I'll re-post there.

Comment: I hope you will get more help there :)